# Kurento Media Server one-2-one call not working?

Tags: java, html, ubuntu, webrtc, kurento

I am having a problem with the kurento-java-tutorial one-2-one-call-recording example and any of the other projects that I run , the problem that when I register a user and try to call another registered user it asks for the camera and mic permission and shows the local camera but the other user camera stays as a spinner , same thing for the 2 users ,

Can you please tell me what I am missing here I followed the installation guide and configuration like what the kurento site described with steps

adding stacktrace  [ modified after fixing the turn server ]:

```
This appears to be Chrome
kurento-utils.js:33 Chrome: using SDP PlanB
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"register","name":"test"}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"registerResponse","response":"accepted"}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"incomingCall","from":"97092673996"}
index.js:70 spec:   {"audio":true,"video":{"width":640,"framerate":15}}
index.js:70 chrome: {"audio":true,"video":{"optional":[{"minWidth":640},{"maxWidth":640},{"minFramerate":15},{"maxFramerate":15}]}}
kurento-utils.js:268 constraints: {"offerToReceiveAudio":true,"offerToReceiveVideo":true}
kurento-utils.js:270 Created SDP offer
kurento-utils.js:275 Local description set v=0
o=- 1791604239915023035 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:dlK6
a=ice-pwd:mRcZcIf0EQ1PnKwVYTAIjNtX
a=fingerprint:sha-256 72:FA:12:B0:1B:8F:9F:E1:15:B0:81:A8:7F:DB:A2:96:50:E8:A4:D4:0A:DD:60:D6:72:52:E1:CF:F0:2F:16:9A
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:1857836482 cname:H8u5HMhixTLRtjPT
a=ssrc:1857836482 msid:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW 6f32b2dd-659e-435b-8e92-acdc99427ac1
a=ssrc:1857836482 mslabel:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW
a=ssrc:1857836482 label:6f32b2dd-659e-435b-8e92-acdc99427ac1
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 102 127 97 99 101 125
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:dlK6
a=ice-pwd:mRcZcIf0EQ1PnKwVYTAIjNtX
a=fingerprint:sha-256 72:FA:12:B0:1B:8F:9F:E1:15:B0:81:A8:7F:DB:A2:96:50:E8:A4:D4:0A:DD:60:D6:72:52:E1:CF:F0:2F:16:9A
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:102 red/90000
a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:125 apt=102
a=ssrc-group:FID 1819201219 3318337897
a=ssrc:1819201219 cname:H8u5HMhixTLRtjPT
a=ssrc:1819201219 msid:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW 7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138
a=ssrc:1819201219 mslabel:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW
a=ssrc:1819201219 label:7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138
a=ssrc:3318337897 cname:H8u5HMhixTLRtjPT
a=ssrc:3318337897 msid:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW 7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138
a=ssrc:3318337897 mslabel:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW
a=ssrc:3318337897 label:7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138

index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"incomingCallResponse","from":"97092673996","callResponse":"accept","sdpOffer":"v=0\r\no=- 1791604239915023035 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:dlK6\r\na=ice-pwd:mRcZcIf0EQ1PnKwVYTAIjNtX\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 72:FA:12:B0:1B:8F:9F:E1:15:B0:81:A8:7F:DB:A2:96:50:E8:A4:D4:0A:DD:60:D6:72:52:E1:CF:F0:2F:16:9A\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1857836482 cname:H8u5HMhixTLRtjPT\r\na=ssrc:1857836482 msid:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW 6f32b2dd-659e-435b-8e92-acdc99427ac1\r\na=ssrc:1857836482 mslabel:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW\r\na=ssrc:1857836482 label:6f32b2dd-659e-435b-8e92-acdc99427ac1\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 102 127 97 99 101 125\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:dlK6\r\na=ice-pwd:mRcZcIf0EQ1PnKwVYTAIjNtX\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 72:FA:12:B0:1B:8F:9F:E1:15:B0:81:A8:7F:DB:A2:96:50:E8:A4:D4:0A:DD:60:D6:72:52:E1:CF:F0:2F:16:9A\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:video\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\na=rtpmap:100 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:102 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000\r\na=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\na=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:125 apt=102\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 1819201219 3318337897\r\na=ssrc:1819201219 cname:H8u5HMhixTLRtjPT\r\na=ssrc:1819201219 msid:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW 7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138\r\na=ssrc:1819201219 mslabel:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW\r\na=ssrc:1819201219 label:7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138\r\na=ssrc:3318337897 cname:H8u5HMhixTLRtjPT\r\na=ssrc:3318337897 msid:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW 7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138\r\na=ssrc:3318337897 mslabel:NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW\r\na=ssrc:3318337897 label:7ee4c497-3220-4fa0-8b23-9b5ab7408138\r\n"}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:2954657374 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.239.1 58914 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2954657374 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.239.1 58914 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:3978421896 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.195.1 58915 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3978421896 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.195.1 58915 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:4175847283 1 udp 2122129151 172.17.150.108 58916 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4175847283 1 udp 2122129151 172.17.150.108 58916 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:2954657374 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.239.1 58917 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2954657374 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.239.1 58917 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:3978421896 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.195.1 58918 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3978421896 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.195.1 58918 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:4175847283 1 udp 2122129151 172.17.150.108 58919 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4175847283 1 udp 2122129151 172.17.150.108 58919 typ host generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:4271866542 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.239.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4271866542 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.239.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:2745309816 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.195.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2745309816 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.195.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:3060114307 1 tcp 1518149375 172.17.150.108 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3060114307 1 tcp 1518149375 172.17.150.108 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:4271866542 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.239.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4271866542 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.239.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 3","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:2745309816 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.195.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2745309816 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.195.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 2","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Local candidate {"candidate":"candidate:3060114307 1 tcp 1518149375 172.17.150.108 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
index.js:70 Senging message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3060114307 1 tcp 1518149375 172.17.150.108 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag dlK6 network-id 1","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"startCommunication","sdpAnswer":"v=0\r\no=- 3709173837 3709173837 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=Kurento Media Server\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS NMuJsVSTnQAmQ5YOQEX1kYierv6zmYhy57LW\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\nm=audio 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=setup:active\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=ssrc:1325200734 cname:user4198751161@host-7c57fee4\r\na=ice-ufrag:+1rl\r\na=ice-pwd:QLVFDoNWIWAHErO+WvOagT\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 FF:F1:5B:82:D1:51:09:08:86:52:5B:EF:34:91:B9:49:45:55:DF:18:8F:A4:D6:21:F0:B3:A1:AB:51:78:87:D6\r\nm=video 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=mid:video\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtpmap:100 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=setup:active\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=ssrc:2706092998 cname:user4198751161@host-7c57fee4\r\na=ice-ufrag:+1rl\r\na=ice-pwd:QLVFDoNWIWAHErO+WvOagT\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 FF:F1:5B:82:D1:51:09:08:86:52:5B:EF:34:91:B9:49:45:55:DF:18:8F:A4:D6:21:F0:B3:A1:AB:51:78:87:D6\r\n"}
kurento-utils.js:321 SDP answer received, setting remote description
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3 1 TCP 1015021823 10.64.5.89 48176 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3 1 TCP 1015021823 10.64.5.89 48176 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 10.64.5.89 41033 typ host","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2 1 TCP 1019216127 10.64.5.89 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2 1 TCP 1019216127 10.64.5.89 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
kurento-utils.js:296 Remote URL: blob:https://10.64.5.89:8443/6058eaf2-90c3-4e23-aaf8-19ed849c47f8
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 10.64.5.89 41033 typ host","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 10.64.5.89 46871 typ host","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 10.64.5.89 46871 typ host","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1015021822 10.64.5.89 38247 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1015021822 10.64.5.89 38247 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019216126 10.64.5.89 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019216126 10.64.5.89 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"sendMessage","from":"test22","to":"test","message":"CustomerPhone : testing - CustomerName : aaaa"}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 1677722111 212.14.226.10 46505 typ srflx raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 46505","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:5 1 TCP 847249663 212.14.226.10 9 typ srflx raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 9 tcptype active","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 1677722111 212.14.226.10 46505 typ srflx raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 46505","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:5 1 TCP 847249663 212.14.226.10 9 typ srflx raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 9 tcptype active","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:6 1 TCP 843055359 212.14.226.10 48176 typ srflx raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 48176 tcptype passive","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:6 1 TCP 843055359 212.14.226.10 48176 typ srflx raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 48176 tcptype passive","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:7 1 UDP 167772671 66.228.45.110 62707 typ relay raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 62707","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
index.js:70 Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:7 1 UDP 167772671 66.228.45.110 62707 typ relay raddr 10.64.5.89 rport 62707","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any public address in candidate's list. Are all your users in same network , if not try using any public stun server. If still it fails then try with TURN. Before doing all this try testing in open network with no firewall.

Comment: how can I do that , and is there any server and port that you can recommend , Regards

Comment: many sites which tell the user is behind which type of firewall. For STUN servers u can check any free STUN server like stun.l.google.com:19302. If you finds u need TURN only then one must have to install our own server or use some service

Comment: I tried to do telnet on the above server and it gave me connection refused

Comment: hey telnet port would be blocked and why do u want to telnet the server. This server is used to get public ip of ur firewall and open some udp/TCP port for communication. Please go through STUN and TURN prtocol , you will understand better.

Comment: I did read about it , and I will check the firewall if there are any rule that block the requests , and way in the kurento tutorial example , I can send messages between the clients the issue that remains only the video and audio streams

Comment: Hello , I tried to create a free user on numb.viagenie.ca and it still the same problem , how can I test that my kurento-server is using the new user

Comment: Requesting to read my comments properly.Try configuring stun and TURN both. Did u try checking what type of firewall you have in your corporate? Please google about topics like STUN,TURN and checking type of firewall. You will get more understanding,These are vast topics.configure both STUN and TURN in Kurento-server config file as mentioned in their documenttaion

Comment: Sirvastava it was access issue ports that the network was blocking

Comment: Would suggest to please upvote the relevant comments or answer so that others facing similar issues will get benefited as yours else SO will delete or demote those over a period of time